# On an Android Device where is located SQLite database, created by Room library

Tags: android, android-room

Where is located an app SQLite database created by Room library on a device?

**Context:**
I have an app which create and use a Room database. To debug the database I would like to open it in a SQLite viewer app but I don't know where the database is located on a testing device.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan This should be posted as an answer

Comment: @Adobles, I have posted it in answer section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you use **Room**, **OrmLite** or **SQLite** in Android all are located within *databases* folder of application package.

You can access the *databases* folder by following below steps.

- ***View*** > ***Tool Windows*** > ***Device File Explorer***

[image]

From *Device File Explorer* go to *data* folder in which all the application packages are stored. Make sure that Emulator or device is connected.

- ***data*** > ***data***

[image]

Then, find you application package and go to your database.

- ***com.company.my*** > ***databases*** > ***yourdatabasename.db***

[image]

You can then save your database in your computer and do anything you want with it.

[image]

I use [SQLiteBrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org) to browse the database.

Answer (score 1):

`Go to Tools -> DDMS` or click the Device File Explorer below Layout Preview in right bar.

Device Monitor window will open.

In File Explorer tab, `click data -> data -> your project name -> databases`.

Click pull a file from device icon. Save the file using .db extension.

I suggest please use Stetho library provided by the Facebook, so you don't need to pull the database every time. You can check the database in browser.

http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Answer (score 1):

You can also debug your database on desktop browser with the help of this awesome library [Android-Debug-Database](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database). Note that your mobile device on which you are running the app and desktop/laptop must be connected to same network.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
String path = getDatabasePath("you_database_name").getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than @musooff answer, if you want to save the database to local storage or want to give a custom path to your database. Then you can use the following approach:

```
val DATABASE_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "MyDBFolder" + File.separator + "example.db"

Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME).build()
```

This will create a folder `MyDBFolder` containing `example.db` database in your local storage. From there you can easily access the database.

Answer (score 0):

- Related to [SQLiteBrowser]

An update to @musooff using SQLiteBrowser to browse the database.

SQLiteBrowser no longer works for Room database Inspection.

You can now use the official Database Inspector for Android Studio.

Select **View > Tool Windows > App Inspection** from the menu bar.